# How to make the streaming operator of the derived class also output the base class

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Let's say I have a class called dogs and inherited from that, a class called shepherd, now I overload the streaming operator for my base class but now when I overload the streaming operator for my derived class I would like it to also output the variables that were originally from my base class.

Obviously I could copy paste the code used for overloading the base class streaming operator, but I was looking for a more elegant solution that didn't involve copying large amounts of code (especially since the real example has a lot more variables inside the base class).

an example.

```
class Dogs
{
 public: 
 int N_legs;
 bool hair_short;
};

class Shepherd : public Dogs
{
 public:
 bool guarding;
};    

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Dogs dogs)
{
 os << "the content of class dogs" << std::endl;
 os << dogs.N_legs << "\t" << dogs.hair_short << std::endl;
 return os;
}
```

Now I tried a dynamic cast but that didn't work.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Shepherd shepherd)
{
 os << dynamic_cast<Dogs>(shepherd);

 os << "The content of class shepherd" << std::endl;
 os << shepherd.guarding << std::endl;
 return os;
};
```

somewhere in main

```
Dogs dogs;
dogs.N_legs = 4;
dogs.hair_short = true;
std::cout << dogs << std::endl;

Shepherd shepherd;
shepherd.N_legs = 4;
shepherd.guarding = true;
std::cout << shepherd << std::endl;
```

Now this will give me an output that only consists of the derived class variables (when you comment out the dynamic cast) but I would also like to have the contents of the base class.

Comment: For polymorphism (and `dynamic_cast`) to work you need to use pointers of *references*. Try passing the argument to the output operator *by reference* instead. Preferably as a constant reference (i.e. `const Shepherd&` and `const Dogs&`, respectively)

Answer (score 1):

[dyanamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) only works with references and pointers, that's why your code can't compile. You should change the parameter type to `const &`, not only for fixing the error, also for avoiding unnecessary copy.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Dogs& dogs)
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Shepherd& shepherd)
{
 os << dynamic_cast<const Dogs&>(shepherd);
 ...
```

BTW: For this case `static_cast` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` is not required here, as you always know that `Dogs` is a base class of `Shepherd`. Simply use `static_cast`:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Shepherd& shepherd)
{
    os << static_cast<const Dogs&>(sheperd);

    os << "The content of class shepherd" << std::endl;
    os << shepherd.guarding << std::endl;

    return os;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `static_cast` instead; you know the base-type at compile-time!

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Shepherd shepherd) {
  os << static_cast<Dogs>(shepherd);
  os << "The content of class shepherd" << std::endl;
  os << shepherd.guarding << std::endl;
  return os;
}
```

[Here's a Wandbox link.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OQYJdxITdd1SiadJ)